# Eliminar rows seleccionados de DGV y DB

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms

Tengo un DGV donde muestro algunos datos de una tabla alojada en SqlServer, cuando digo algunos me refiero a que tengo un SP que me trae solo los datos que quiero mostrar en el DGV.

Lo que quiero es que el usuario pueda seleccionar los rows que quiera eliminar y con un botón, eliminar de la tabla y DGV los registros seleccionados.

Mi tabla tiene 9 columnas y en el DGV solo muestro 4 de ellas:

```
IdEvent, int
Coordinate_x, int
Coordinate_y, int
IdMov, String
```

Y este es el código que estoy tratando de utilizar para eliminar las filas seleccionadas, pero no me lo hace, enseguida que doy clic me salta a la línea del Else.

Este es el código que estoy utilizando:

```
private void btnDel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.DGVEvents.SelectedRows)
        {
            cnx.Open();
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Event WHERE idEvent =@Index", cnx);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Index", item.Index);
                int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cnx.Close();

                if (i != 0)
                {
                    DGVEvents.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);
                    MessageBox.Show("Deleted Succefull!", "Great", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Deleted Failed!", "Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sql not execute", "Error Sql" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Cual puede ser el error que estoy cometiendo?

Espero me puedan ayudar.

DS

Comment: Es probable que la propiedad `item.Index` en realidad te esté devolviendo el índice de la fila del DataGridView, en lugar del índice del objeto en la base de datos. Por eso el delete no te devuelve ningún row afectado

Comment: Y como puedo hacer que me devuelva el indice del objeto base de datos?
@Arriel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daniel.

La propiedad Index del elemento item (que es un DataViewGridRow) no te devuelve el índice del objeto, te devuelve el índice (con base cero) del row que pertenece al data grid view. Es decir, si tu objeto está de primero, el índice que te va a devolver será cero siempre.

Para obtener el índice del objeto, deberás saber cómo se llama la columna que trae el Id del objeto. Según entiendo, se llama IdEvent, entonces tu código deberá ser cambiado a:

```
//el resto de tu código

 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Event WHERE idEvent =@Index", cnx);

 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Index", item.Cells["IdEvent"].Value);
 int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

//el resto de tu código
```

Inténtalo y me dices cómo te queda.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha funcionado @Arriel